# Why do we have to mention "withCredentials" for XHR but not for a page refresh?

Tags: http, browser

I'm not sure if this is a dumb question, but a browser will respond with the user's credentials if it's a page refresh, but won't for an XHR that does not have "withCredentials" set. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

`withCredentials` is for cross-site requests only.

It seems to me this design makes sense. The request originated from some different website/application. It might not care about the user's credentials. So it can choose not to set this option.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it will be http request going to the server, even if it was for updating\refreshing part of the page without the credentials you will not be allowed to use XHR.
Refer for [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).